# how to ask user input numbers in array in textbox1 and display in textbox2

Tags: c#, indexoutofrangeexception

I have two textboxes, textbox1 will have numbers input by the user if user input numbers more than 4 an exception handling indexoutofrange will occur. But, I get an error saying that:

> cannot convert from 'string[]' to string.

How can I solve the error and how to input array numbers?

```
int[] answer =int.Parse(textBox3.Text.Split(new Char[] { ',' }));

for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    answer[i] = int.Parse(jawapanD17193.Text);
}
```

Comment: @MongZhu,how is this a duplicate of the link you provided ? The op is facing a different problem , right ?

Comment: @zackraiyan I read it the first time not carefull enough. Then retracted my close-vote, but the comment was not removed automatically. now it's all back to zero

Comment: @MongZhu , it's oke...I hope OP finds your solution helpful ... :)

Comment: " how to input array numbers?" what exactly do you mean by this?

Comment: @MongZhu i mean i want to input list of numbers like 1,2,3,4. Then the numbers array numbers. i don't know to explain it. i mean the int answer = {1,2,3,4};

Answer (score 2):

Problem: The [Int.Parse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h1hf19(v=vs.110).aspx) method expects a `string` as input. And [string.Split](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a(v=vs.110).aspx) returns a `string []`.

Solution: You would need to reverse your conversion:

```
int[] answer = textBox3.Text.Split(new Char[] { ',' }).Select(x=> int.Parse(x)).ToArray();
```

This way around you will parse each element in the `string []` and you will have an array of `int` in the end.

You don't need to declare an extra char array: `new Char[] { ',' }`. If you read the documentation you can see that `Split` takes a

> params char[] separator

as parameter. So handing it char by char will be ok:

```
int[] answer = textBox3.Text.Split(',').Select(x=> int.Parse(x)).ToArray();
```

EDIT:

Sometimes a space can mess up the conversion. You can remove it using `Trim()`

```
    int[] answer = textBox3.Text.Split(',').Select(x=> int.Parse(x.Trim())).ToArray();
```

Comment: i got error message saying that "input string was not in a correct format".  i entered the numbers, example : 1,2,2,1

Comment: @nikina may be you have a space in there. I edited my post to show how you can get rid of it. Have a look

Comment: @nikina then you should maybe try the overload of split that can specify stringsplitoptions

Answer (score 1):

`int.Parse` expects a single `string` as input, but you are passing the results of `string.Split` to it, which is a `string[]`.

Use a loop or LINQ `Select` to pass each individual string from the array to `int.Parse`.

```
using System.Linq;

int[] answers = textBox3.Text
    .Split(new Char[] { ',' })
    .Select(str => int.Parse(str))
    .ToArray();
```

Comment: looks like mong zhu beat you by about 50 seconds :)

Comment: Yes. And we came up with the same solution :)